# SWF file not opening in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, flash, swfobject, swfloader, adobe-flash-cs3

I have a package file which includes the collection of SWF files and HTML files. and when I run HTML file it shows the SWF file running in IE, however, it is not running in chrome and firefox.

Please find the package here
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjJr1bSruSFCvjyLOaQtlWE4co0L

Comment: always show what you have done so far

Comment: is Shockwave Flash installed on those browsers?

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Comment: can you show your code? Are there any errors shown in the browser consoles of those browsers?

Comment: Please find it here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjJr1bSruSFCvjyLOaQtlWE4co0L

Comment: With all respect I am not going to download a random zip file from a stranger, sorry :-) . As per SO guidance please post the _relevant parts of_ your code _here_ for people to read and understand. Links to 3rd-party resources can go stale, and even if I downloaded your zip I'm not going to sit and wade through your whole application to find the relevant bits. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on how to structure your question better

Comment: you also didn't answer my question about error messages.

Comment: Code
=============================

Comment: it does not throw any error. it shows only loading screen. the code is too long and I am not able to identify the portion of an error.

Comment: in that case I apologise but I can't help any further. Without any code or error reports it's impossible to identify the source of the problem.

Comment: @Ramesh we need a testable URL link to some `.swf` on your (website) server. **Show your code** means show us a minimum testable code to **recreate** your issue. Something like [**this code**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed). No downloading any `.zip` is needed to fix this.

Comment: PS: Chrome is strict about directly opening an `*.swf` file alone within a browser tab. An swf file can only be viewed through loading (`<embed>`) inside an html page.

Comment: there are the a number of SWF files which run as frames..it loading first few frames for loading screen but after that frames are not moving